# Process to Sum Outputs of a Function

Tags: summation

I was wondering if there was any process to take the sum of any given functions outputs akin to a integrals to sum the area under the curve. For example, if my function is
$$ \frac { \left( x - \frac 1 2 \right) ^ 2 } 2 \text , $$
and I want to find the area under the curve from $ x = 1 $ to $ x = 10 $. I would integrate from $ 1 $ to $ 10 $.

What if I want the sum of all $ Y $ values corresponding to $ x = 1 $ to $ x = 10 $ of the function without computing each separately? Is there anyway I can reduce this operation into one problem instead of plugging in $ 10 $ different values?

Answer (score 0):

You could say $$\sum\limits_{x=1}^{10} \frac { \left( x - \frac 1 2 \right) ^ 2 } 2 = \frac18 {  \sum\limits_{x=1}^{10}\left( 2x - 1 \right) ^ 2 }  = \frac18 {  \sum\limits_{m=1}^{20}m ^ 2 } - \frac18 {  \sum\limits_{m=1}^{10}(2m) ^ 2 }= \frac18 {  \sum\limits_{m=1}^{20}m ^ 2 } - \frac12 {  \sum\limits_{m=1}^{10}m ^ 2 } $$

It then helps if you know that $\sum\limits_{m=1}^n m^2 = \frac16 n(n+1)(2n+1)$